# Scheduling tasks to employees with overrides for vacation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ice-cube

I am trying to implement a feature where employees are rotating a tasks assignment based on the schedule created. In most cases, employees are assigned a task on a rotating daily, weekly, biweekly, or monthly basis.

For example, we have 4 employees: John, Peter, Avit, Jane
For a daily schedule, John may be responsible for the task the first week, Peter the second week, etc

There are also times where an employee might be on vacation. For example, John is on PTO for the first 2 days while he is assigned to the task and Avit takes over for those 2 days, when John is back on Day 3 he takes back the task assignment. I am trying to figure out how I can implement such a scheduling feature with ice_cube.

I know how to create a schedule with reoccurrence and exceptions. But I am not sure how to incorporate this with the concept of rotating amongst a set of users with overrides.

I have implemented a model called ScheduleUser, which stores the user_id and priority value. I have a delayed job that runs on each occurrence date/time which rotates the value in the priority column for each user. The person assigned to the task is the one with the highest priority.

This works fine for the simple use case, however when I have to override (partially or for the entire duration) an employee assignment then this doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Gurpreet! Didn't you already ask this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64525991/1880203

Comment: @Chiperific thanks. this question is regarding how to override a rotating schedule in the event the employee is on vacation. The other question is regarding predicting the schedule used in the case of a simple rotation every day/week/monthly. This is specifically regarding how to implement overrides to the rotation

Comment: @jvillian "I am not sure how to incorporate this with the concept of rotating amongst a set of users with overrides"

Comment: @GurpreetDhaliwal, some draft code, or code you've tried will really help us out. It's hard for us to start from scratch. Include your `ScheduleUser` model and any methods you've tried.

Comment: "this doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525991/get-rotating-user-for-ice-cube-recurrence-rule) on this topic, I suggest you have a field in your database that allows you to exclude users from the `schedule_users` method.

```rb
validates_presence_of :name, :start, :frequency, :project
    
  def next_occurrence
    ice_cube_schedule.next_occurrence.start_time
  end

  def jobs
    Delayed::Job.where('handler LIKE ?', "%Schedule/#{id}\%")
  end

  def on_call_user
    # This should not include any users that are unavailable
    schedule_users.max_by(&:priority).user if users.present?
  end

  def priority(user)
    # This should not include any users that are unavailable
    schedule_users.where(user: user).first.try(:priority)
  end

  ...
end
```

So, in your `User` model you could have a `scope` that prevents `unavailable` users from being selected:

```
class User
  # we will need a boolean database field called "unavailable"

  scope :available, -> { where(unavailable: false) }

  ...
end
```

Then you can call `User.all.available` (or `@users.available`) to only get "available" users.

### What about covering for each other?

Maybe I'm over-simplifying this, your example is quite a complex piece of logic:

> John is on PTO for the first 2 days while he is assigned to the task and Avit takes over for those 2 days, when John is back on Day 3 he takes back the task assignment

If John is already on PTO, why would he be assigned a task? Why wouldn't it just default to Avit? This is what I'm driving at above.

If you want a way to manually make John take over the task on Day 3, you just need to `destroy` or `edit` the existing, active `ice_cube` schedule, right?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I think I will take your approach and capture whether a user is on PTO or not using a flag on the user table or create a new PTO table that stores the PTO date range (that way the user doesn't have to disable the flag when they are back). I would then have a delayed job that runs at the start and end dates specified for PTO which will toggle this flag on or off. We can then ignore the users with this flag set.